# Quick question about Ajax.ActionLink and span

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple question.

I have the following html code

```
<a href="#" class="purchase">
<span>Purchase</span><em>@string.Format("{0:C0}", Model.thisItem.ItemSalePrice)</em>
</a>
```

But I want to use a Ajax.Actionlink to make it as a ajax post.

I have the following updated code

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Purchase", "AddToCart", "Browse", new { ItemID = Model.thisItem.ItemID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "content" }, new { @class = "purchase" })
```

The question is how I can put the  tag into the actionlink?

Thank you everyone.

**UPDATES**

I also got an answer from ASP.NET's forum, and it is even easier.
http://forums.asp.net/p/1702210/4518688.aspx/1?p=True&t=634468566867949718

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify it in the action link text parameter:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(String.Format("{0} {1}", "Purchase", String.Format("{0:C0}", Model.thisItem.ItemSalePrice)), "AddToCart", "Browse", new { ItemID = Model.thisItem.ItemID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "content" }, new { @class = "purchase" })
```

EDIT 1:
Other overloads are not shown, but this should be enough to get you started.
If you need more details, you can take a look at the MVC3 source and see how they setup their helpers.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, float salePrice, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return CustomActionLink(htmlHelper, linkText, salePrice, actionName, controllerName, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString CustomActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, float salePrice, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        var url = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

        // Build the <span> tag
        var spanBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
        spanBuilder.SetInnerText(linkText);
        string spanHtml = spanBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        // Build the <em> tag
        var emBuilder = new TagBuilder("em");
        emBuilder.SetInnerText(String.Format("{0:C0}", salePrice));
        string emHtml = emBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        // Build the <a> tag
        var anchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
        anchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues));
        anchorBuilder.InnerHtml = spanHtml + emHtml;
        string anchorHtml = anchorBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchorHtml);
    }
```

Note: `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes` is under the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your reply. However, it doesn't work. The rendered html code is different from my target code...

Comment: Ah so u would like it exactly with `<em>`? You wouldn't be able to do that with existing helpers since they output it as `<a>` directly. You'd need to write a custom helper for that (see edited answer). Also, the example I gave is indeed for the HTML helper, but it should serve as a good place to start and look at the AJAX helpers in the MVC3 source.